# Проверь наличия id в связанной таблицы?

Tags: laravel

Это работает, но есть одна проблема — в `{two}` можно написать все что угодно и ошибки не будет. `404` ошибка будет только в том случае, если указанный `id` из `{three}` не будет найден в таблице. В этом и суть проблемы.

**Routes**

```
Route::get('one/{two}/{three}', 'MyController@show')->name('three.show');
Route::get('one/{two}/{three}/edit', 'MyController@edit')->name('three.edit');
```

**Controller**

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
   // ...

    public function edit($two, $three)
    {
        $variable = ThirdModel::findOrFail($three);

        return view('three.edit', compact('variable'));
    }

    // ...
}
```

Модели относящиеся к маршрутам `{two}` и `{three}` имеют связь. Было бы здорово перед `ThirdModel::findOrFail($three)` проверить наличие `id` в связанной таблицы `TwoModel`. Этого можно как-то добиться?

**Model**

```
class ThirdModel extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function MyMethod()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\TwoModel');
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас есть связь между таблицами, значит есть и колонка(foreign key) через которую они связываются.
Сделайте выборку по двум колонкам.

```
public function edit($two, $three)
{
    $variable = ThirdModel::where(['id' => $three, 'two_id' => $two])->firstOrFail();

    return view('three.edit', compact('variable'));
}
```

Comment: То что мне было нужно, спасибо.